# Typo3: More Domains, same content

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a typo3 installation with a site for a domain (i call it aaa.com). Now I have a new domain (i call it bbb.com) which links on the correct page aaa.com/muster. The goal is that when i go to bbb.com the url is like this: bbb.com/muster and not. aaa.com/muster.

Can anybody fix me?

Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that you might suffer a penalty in search engines for providing the same content on multiple domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

If you don't want to create a new page, then you can do it using typoscript also like:

```
[globalVar=IENV:TYPO3_HOST_ONLY=www.bbb.com]
config.baseURL = http://www.aaa.com/
[end]
```

or

```
[globalVar=IENV:TYPO3_HOST_ONLY=www.bbb.com]
page.config.additionalHeaders = Location: http://www.aaa.com/muster
[end]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new page outsite the page tree of aaa.com and add a domain record in that page with url: domain - http://bbb.com. Then in "Redirect to:" field enter http://aaa.com/muster.